# How can I fix 'Trying to access array offset on value of type bool' error in my PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, notice

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
```

I got this for each loop:

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    if (stripos($field['name'], 'label_') !== FALSE) {
        echo '';
    }
    else{
        $val = get_field_object($field['name'], $id);
        echo '<td>'.generate_view($field['name'], $val['value']).'</td>';
    }
}
```

The error is saying this line is incorrect:

```
echo '<td>'.generate_view($field['name'], $val['value']).'</td>';
```

This error just came for the first time and I realy need to fix it but I don't know what it is saying and how to solve. Anyone can help me out?

I searched and found other posts regarding this issue on Stackoverflow but can't figure out to translate the answers in order to fix my problem:(

Comment: `$val` is a boolean, probably false, so `get_field_object()` didn't return what you think it should

Comment: @aynber, thank you for the response. Is there a way to prevent this or hide the notice error? I allready hide all errors in my WordPress environment but this one still shows up...

Comment: Wrap the echo statement into `if($val) { ... }`?

Comment: I would probably change that line to a ternary to make sure the value exists. `echo $val ? '<td>'.generate_view($field['name'], $val['value']).'</td>' : '';`, or add an if/else for better readability

Answer (score 1):

check if $val is null echo '';

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $val = get_field_object($field['name'], $id);
    if (stripos($field['name'], 'label_') !== FALSE OR !$val) {
        echo '';
    } else{
        echo '<td>'.generate_view($field['name'], $val['value']).'</td>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted with the due, readable checks. Feel free to shorten or modify it.

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $view_content = '';

    // Captures $val
    $val = get_field_object($field['name'], $id);

    // Checks if $val is an array or not
    $val_is_array = (array)$val === $val;

    // Checks for label validity
    $valid = stripos($field['name'], 'label_') !== FALSE;

    // Only fills $view_content when both conditions are met
    if ($valid && $val_is_array) {
        $view_content = '<td>'.generate_view($field['name'], $val['value']).'</td>';
    }

    // Outputs it
    echo $view_content;
}
```